# ServiceStack catch (WebServiceException ex) - has wrong ErrorCode

Tags: exception, servicestack

In my ServiceStack service, I throw an exception that has an inner exception. When I caught a WebServiceRequest on the client side, the ErrorCode was the inner exception type name.

This is bad for me because it doesn't allow me to respond to the specific exception type that was thrown on the server.

I'm failing to see why ServiceStack was designed this way. It's pretty typical to catch lower level exceptions and wrap them with more informative and sometimes end-user friendly exceptions.

How can I change the default behavior so it uses the surface level exception and not the inner-most?

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the first example at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling, I decided to check out at [DtoUtils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/ServiceHost/DtoUtils.cs).HandleException, which looks like this:

```
    public static object HandleException(IResolver iocResolver, object request, Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException != null && !(ex is IHttpError))
            ex = ex.InnerException;

        var responseStatus = ex.ToResponseStatus();

        if (EndpointHost.DebugMode)
        {
            // View stack trace in tests and on the client
            responseStatus.StackTrace = GetRequestErrorBody(request) + ex;
        }

        Log.Error("ServiceBase<TRequest>::Service Exception", ex);

        if (iocResolver != null)
            LogErrorInRedisIfExists(iocResolver.TryResolve<IRedisClientsManager>(), request.GetType().Name, responseStatus);

        var errorResponse = CreateErrorResponse(request, ex, responseStatus);

        return errorResponse;
    }
```

The very first instruction replaces the exception with it's inner exception. I'm not sure what the the thinking was with that. It seems counter intuitive to me and so I just re-implemented the method in my AppHost class, removing that first if statement block:

```
    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        ServiceExceptionHandler += (request, exception) => HandleException(this, request, exception);
    }

    /// <remarks>
    /// Verbatim implementation of DtoUtils.HandleException, without the innerexception replacement.
    /// </remarks>
    public static object HandleException(IResolver iocResolver, object request, Exception ex)
    {
        var responseStatus = ex.ToResponseStatus();

        if (EndpointHost.DebugMode)
        {
            // View stack trace in tests and on the client
            responseStatus.StackTrace = DtoUtils.GetRequestErrorBody(request) + ex;
        }

        var log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DtoUtils));
        log.Error("ServiceBase<TRequest>::Service Exception", ex);

        if (iocResolver != null)
            DtoUtils.LogErrorInRedisIfExists(iocResolver.TryResolve<IRedisClientsManager>(), request.GetType().Name, responseStatus);

        var errorResponse = DtoUtils.CreateErrorResponse(request, ex, responseStatus);

        return errorResponse;
    }
```

This is obviously not ideal, since I had to copy a bunch of code that is totally unrelated to the problem that I had with the original implementation. It makes me feel like I have to maintain this method whenever I update ServiceStack. I would love to here of a better way to accomplish this.

Anyway, I have the exception handling that I like in my client code:

```
catch (WebServiceException ex)
{
    if (ex.ErrorCode == typeof (SomeKindOfException).Name)
    {
        // do something useful here
    }
    else throw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you'll have to maintain a bunch of code. You're writing one method to implement your own error handling. You could try calling DtoUtils.HandleException(this, request, exception) in your own method and  modify the HttpError object returned. Not sure you have access to change all properties/values you're looking for.

```
public static object HandleException(IResolver iocResolver, object request, Exception ex)
{
    HttpError err = (HttpError)DtoUtils.HandleException(this, request, ex);
    err.Reponse = ex.InnerException; 
}
```